# Chrome Console Bug When Debugging Javascript

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome console tells you what line in the parsed file JavaScript syntax errors are located.  Every once in a while, when I click on the link to take me to see the actual code of where the error is, I get a blank screen in the console.  If I open up the same page inside Firefox with Firebug, I can see the error code without any issues.

Is this a known error in Chrome?  If so, are there any ways to remedy it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an official list of known issues with Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/known-issues/15036?hl=en). It doesn't seem like that is one of the known issues. I would try again and see if it happens again.